# Apache Ignite with Spring framework

Tags: ignite

Does the Apache Ignite operate on a spring framework basis? 
Can I register a spring controller in classpath at server remote node and use it?(using component , like @Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Ignite is integrated with Spring but isn't based on it.

You can register spring beans when starting remote node (using normal spring approach) and then use them from e.g. compute or distributed services.

I'm not sure if you can register beans remotely in runtime, but I don't see why not.

Comment: I create a java class(TestController.java) using @Controller annotation and add classpath. But I don't think It was scan because I set RequestMapping("test/view")and call url using browser. Is it other way to scan component in Ignite?  or Is it automatically scan if i use Controller, Service annotation??

Comment: Ignite will not scan anything. Whether Spring will scan anything depends on your configuration. How do you configure Ignite?

Comment: What should I configure for Spring will scan??

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should configure Spring?